# Can’t get required (SVOX) languages in android tts

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have an application that should implement tts in several languages. Those languages are not available with standard PICO engine, so I need SVOX or something similar.
I have installed SVOX and the required voices, hover I can’t change my phone tts engine (I have android 2.1, so there is not this option, and I can’t install tts extended app either, as my phone is not compatible).

I probably should somehow change the engine in use programmatically, but I don’t seem able to do that.

Here is my code: this works if I use standard voices, and those I need are not available

```
public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {


        Locale[] AvalLoc = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

        Log.i("TTS","Available locales " + Arrays.toString(AvalLoc));
               /*
                   JUST TRYING TO OUTPUT WHICH LANGUAGES ARE AVAILABLE
                 */
         for (Locale l : AvalLoc) {
             int buf = tts.setLanguage(l);

             if (buf == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                     || buf == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                 Log.i("TTS", "Language NOT available" + l.getCountry());
             } else {
                 Log.i("TTS","Language available" + l.getCountry());
             }


         }


        Locale loc = new Locale("ita","ITA"); /*This works, but I would need to be able to use SVOX voices instead*/

        int result = tts.setLanguage(loc);
        tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(onUtteranceCompleted);


        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
          btnSpeakQuestion.setEnabled(true); 
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

}
```

I have both standard and SVOX TTS installed.

Comment: PS: the page for developers at SVOX website does not help, since it only tells about how to provide the voices the final user should download...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with pt_BR locale and in order to use SVOX from my Android device, I had  to change the default TTS Engine using setEngineByPackageName method (which is deprecated by the way).

Using SVOX Classic, you should change TTS engine giving the package name:

```
int result = tts.setEngineByPackageName("com.svox.classic");
if( result == TextToSpeech.ERROR ) {
    //Could not find svox classic
}
```

According to [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) you should not use this method since it will not inform callers that TTS has been initialized. But at least will help to test SVOX within different languages.

By the way, once you change TTS engine, set locale has no effect:

```
int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```

Even using set language above after change TTS engine my app keeps using SVOX configuration (pt_BR).

**Important**: Mentioned method works only when SVOX is enabled on TTS Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure about your license? SVOX is now bought by Nuance.

Comment: I’m open to any alternative, as long as I get this working. In any case, according to the svox developer page there should’t be problems, as far as I uderstand